# Transpose a matrix created by h5py

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

I have a h5py data that looks like this.

```
import h5py
f = h5py.File('X.h5', 'w')
f['X'] = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]])
>>> f['X'][...]
    array([[0, 0],
           [0, 1],
           [1, 0],
           [1, 1]])
```

I want transpose of above data. It might be easy for small data, but what if I have very huge data?

Comment: Does `np.transpose` do the job?

Comment: Do you want a transposed numpy array held in memory, or do you actually want to transpose the data stored on disk?

Comment: I want transpose of data stored on disk @ali_m

Comment: How much RAM do you have and what are the `.shape`, `.dtype` and `.chunks` attributes of your dataset? Can I also ask why you want to transpose the data on disk, rather than simply changing the way you index into it?

Comment: Transposing a matrix means rearranging the elements. This will take a read and a write. For very huge data you will need very huge memory or a lot time (read in strides). As ali_m or hpaulj say, use something different like a view or transpose after reading only.